# Rewriting (X+)? as X* in ANTLR grammars

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grammar

At https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

I'm finding lots of instances of `(X+)?`.

Shouldn't these be replaced with `X*`?

Here are a set of instances I've found with my own analysis tool:

```
sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4(1654,11): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 39760
sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4(1754,27): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 42796
sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4(1786,31): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 43928
sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4(1815,31): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 44865
sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4(2233,74): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 56180
sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4(2245,12): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 56458
sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4(2490,82): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 62412
sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4(2577,137): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 64544
sql/mysql/Positive-Technologies/MySqlLexer.g4(1176,50): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 53848
sql/mysql/Positive-Technologies/MySqlLexer.g4(1178,52): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 53988
sql/mysql/Positive-Technologies/MySqlLexer.g4(1176,50): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 53848
sql/mysql/Positive-Technologies/MySqlLexer.g4(1178,52): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 53988
sql/tsql/TSqlParser.g4(2410,13): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 84325
sql/tsql/TSqlParser.g4(2459,13): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 86539
informix/informix.g4(2879,25): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 35322
antlr/antlr2/examples/python.g2(660,48): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 13664
antlr/antlr2/examples/java.g2(905,4): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 25794
cql3/CqlLexer.g4(996,19): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 8042
cql3/CqlLexer.g4(996,88): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 8111
cql3/CqlLexer.g4(996,19): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 8042
cql3/CqlLexer.g4(996,88): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 8111
restructuredtext/ReStructuredText.g4(100,49): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 2632
fortran77/Fortran77Parser.g4(433,61): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 7722
fortran77/Fortran77Parser.g4(437,47): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 7790
fortran77/Fortran77Parser.g4(441,48): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 7861
verilog/verilog/Verilog2001.g4(366,68): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 10098
verilog/verilog/Verilog2001.g4(370,33): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 10164
verilog/verilog/Verilog2001.g4(370,67): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 10198
prov-n/PROV_N.g4(28,63): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 1253
cobol85/Cobol85.g4(174,47): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 4773
vb6/VisualBasic6Parser.g4(110,41): Warning: rewrite as `X*`, token `?` at offset 2788
```

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. `(x+)?` is equivalent to `x*`. Looking at the generated code and the ATNs, while they may look different, the generated code from one can be refactored into the other, with all the calls to ErrorHandler.Sync() and TokenStream.LA() matching up, but the code and ATN for the Kleene star version cleaner though. At least one pattern in Antlrvsix.Trash notation for this is `"//ebnf[blockSuffix/ebnfSuffix/QUESTION and block/altList[@ChildCount = 1]/alternative[@ChildCount = 1]/element/ebnf/blockSuffix/ebnfSuffix/PLUS]"`, but it looks like there are others. Good catch.

Comment: Please make a pull request to grammars repository with such changes if you can.